# Java:: Why isn't this implementation of Fibonacci sequence with memoization not work?

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, fibonacci

I have a quick question about implementing the Fibonacci sequence using the memoization (DP). I am using a HashTable, but for some reason, the table never seems to contain the elements. I inserted a print statement to print out something whenever a value was read from the hashtable and it seems like this never happens. I feel like its a simple fix, but I don't see it.

```
  public static int getFib(int n) {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> dictionary = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        if (n <= 2)
            return 1;
        else if (dictionary.containsKey(n)) {
            System.out.println("Reading From Table");
            return dictionary.get(n);
        } else {
            int val = getFib(n - 1) + getFib(n - 2);
            dictionary.put(n, val);
            return val;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 'memoization', not 'memorization'.

Comment: (-/ Starts with double colon, double negation and no continuous form in the title /-). Pertaining to code: in declarations, prefer interfaces over implementations. Avoid one hit on the Map: use a variable `result = dictionary.get(n); if (null != result) …`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling getFib() recursively, and instantiating a new dictionary with each call. Make the dictionary a class-level variable.

Answer (score 4):

`dictionary` is a `local variable` so the scope of this variable is within the function `getFib`.

If you call the function `getFib` recursively then each time the `hash map will be created and instantiated` and the `scope of the hashmap dictionary will end on returning from the function`.

You can have a `global variable` instead to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

**Initialize the dictionary outside your method.**
Right now, you are creating a new 'dictionary' in each recursive call.

Answer (score 2):

Make the `dictionary` a member variable rather than a local variable

```
private HashMap<Integer, Integer> dictionary = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

public static int getFib(int n) {

    // some operations
}
```